# Remove Block Programmatically in Magento2

Tags: magento2

We are able to remove block in Magento1 with `unsetBlock()` method, but in Magento2 it is not working. So, please help how can remove block in Magento2  programmatically ?

Comment: What do you mean with `programmatically` ?  Is a solution with XML good too?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `unsetElement()` method to remove block. 
as like

```
$layout = $this->getLayout();
$block = $layout->getBlock('catalog.topnav'); // block name
$layout->unsetElement('catalog.topnav');
```

Comment: I'm trying to remove the `contactForm` like this, but without success...

Comment: @GielBerkers: how you are removing in block or controller. can you share your code ?

Comment: Whats the class of $layout ? And why do you create a variable `$block` if you never use it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to try this way, for example, I am removing compare from the sidebar so I override `default.xml` to `app/design/frontend/Your_Theme/theme_name/Magento_Catalog/layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To Remove particular block from page, Open your custom layout xml and        place the below code under body Tag

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body><referenceBlock name="Your_Block" remove="true"/>
    </body>
    </page>
```

Change Your_Block this one to your block name need to be remove

Answer (score 0):

Ideally there are different ways to do this. The best way of doing it is using a layout file.

1) If you have build a module you can create a layout which is an xml file in app/code/Namespace/Your_Module/view/frontend/layout/frontname_controllername_controlleraction.xml and add the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true" />
</page>
```

2) If you have not created a custom module of your's you can simply write a custom xml in app/design/frontend/Custom_Theme/Theme_name/Module_Name/layout and add the below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true" />
</page>
```